# How to better handle IIS app pool recycle in web services

Tags: web, iis

I am running a web service in IIS which calls a third party vendor application. The web service is called from yet another third party application to which the IIS hosted web service replies to. So basically My App -> IIS App -> Third Party App -> IIS App-> My App.

Occasionally, there are app pool recycles which the Third party App is executing, meaning the IIS app is waiting for the reply. This causes the My App to indefinitely wait on the Third Party app because the singnalling chain is now broken.

Is it by design that IIS will force kill the child process running in it during recycles? Is there a way to make the recycle wait till the child is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set Disable Overlapped Reycle

[image]

If you set it to **true**, then IIS recycle will terminate the old process instance and create a new one immediately.

How if you were setting it to false, Then IIS Recycling will not terminate old process and requests immediately. You can see there are two instance side by side if the old process haven't finish all requests.

[image]

It will create a new application pool as well. The difference is IIS will leave the old process until all requests in old worker process being finished or shut down time exceed the **ShutDown Time limit**. Its default value is 90
[image]

So if your old request didn't hang in the old worker process and it require more than 90s to finish the request, please just expand the value of **ShutDown Time Limit**. It will give your old process more time to handle current requests.

Comment: The shutdown time limit did help in that the worker process lived longer. But what is happening is that the w3wp is going into suspended state and and my process is still unable to complete its response. Also it ended up creating a vs debugger process, which makes it look like my process crashed. Is there a way that we can NOT suspend the worker process?